# cannot activate the 'ros' extension because it depends on an unknown 'ms-vscode.cpptools' extension. on code server

Tags: vscode-extensions, ros, ros2, python-extensions, code-server

So I was trying to learn ROS2 iron on the Ubuntu Server. I installed the Ubuntu server on a Raspberry Pi 4 and I used my laptop to SSH into the Raspberry Pi 4. Next, I installed ROS2 iron on the machine and double-checked to make sure that it was working. However to write the ROS2 codes I needed a coding IDE and I opted to use Code-Server instead of SSHing from VSCode (Because SShing from VScode was unstable and would constantly disconnect).

This is where I started encountering some problems. The extension library on the Code-Server does not have all the extensions that I needed to code my ROS2 nodes. To be specific I needed the "ros" extension which is developed by Microsoft. To fix this issue I downloaded the "ms-iot.vscode-ros-0.9.5.vsix" file from MarketPlace and installed it in the code server. The installation was completed and it was successful.

However, I received the following notification:
cannot activate the 'ros' extension because it depends on an unknown 'ms-vscode.cpptools' extension. on code server

Note that the ros extension is installed and is enabled on the Code-Server (Refer to picture 1), but when I try to import the extension into my code I receive the following error (Refer to Picture 2):
No module named 'rclpy'

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]

Any help would be appreciated.

So far I have done the following to fix the issue and none have worked:

1. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the extension.
2. I reloaded the Code-server page multiple times.
3. I installed the C/C++ extension made by Microsoft version V1.17.5 and V1.18.0

Comment: You have to source the ROS 2 environment. Please run `. /opt/ros/iron/setup.bash` before executing the Python file

Comment: Please do not post code as picture, so other people with the same problem can find the answer faster. Read the Hot to ask for more information: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask